# transform large price table to table with startdate and enddate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with prices per article per date with a lot of redundancy: even if the price does not change, I still have a line for each date. What I would like to do is transform this table to a table where for every different price, there will be a new line with a **startdate** and **enddate**.

Source example:

```
article_ID  date       price
1           01/01/15   2.99
1           02/01/15   2.99
1           03/01/15   2.49
2           01/01/15   12.29
2           02/01/15   12.29
2           03/01/15   12.29
```

I am looking for an SQL query to create the following result:

```
article_ID  startdate  enddate   price
1           01/01/15   02/01/15  2.99
1           03/01/15   03/01/15  2.49
2           01/01/15   03/01/15  12.49
```

I work with SQL Server and Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: GROUP BY article_ID, price? What if an article changes back to a previous price?

Comment: @jarlh That can happen, then a new line should be created with the new startdate: if the price of article 1 goes back to 2.99 on January 4th, then the new line has a startdate of 04/01/15 and a price of 2.99.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify rows of consecutive dates with the same price, and then group on the resulting identifier.  A simpler way to get the group is to subtract an increasing sequence, generated by `row_number()`:

```
select article_id, min(date) as startdate, max(date) as enddate, price
from (select s.*,
             dateadd(day,
                     - row_number() over (partition by article_id, price
                                          order by date
                                         )
                     date) as grp
      from source s
     ) s
group by grp, article_id, price;
```

If you have the possibility of missed dates, then a difference of row numbers works:

```
select article_id, min(date) as startdate, max(date) as enddate, price
from (select s.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by article_id order by date) -
              row_number() over (partition by article_id, price order by date)
             ) as grp
      from source s
     ) s
group by grp, article_id, price;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
INSERT INTO destinationtable (article_ID,startdate,enddate.price)
    SELECT article_ID, MIN(date) AS startdate, MAX(date) AS enddate, price
    FROM sourcetable
    GROUP BY article_ID, price
```

This will not work properly if a price changes back to a previous value. If that is a chance you will have to run a procedural code that loops while price stays constant and tracks start and end date.